# Android animation z-index

Tags: android, animation, z-index, android-relativelayout

I'm using relative layout, and I have the following items inside of them

```
<foo
    android:id="@+id/first_one" >

<bar
    android:id="@+id/second_one"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first_one" >
```

I want to start an animation on `bar` but it should be z-indexed behind `foo`. The thing is that in order to do that, I need to declare `foo` after `bar`. BUT I can't do that, because since `bar` is supposed to be below `foo`   it throws null pointer exception.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RelativeLayout has many possibilities. Try this:

```
<bar
    android:id="@+id/second_one">

<foo
    android:id="@+id/first_one"
    android:layout_above="@+id/second_one">
```